# collect values from csv file?

Tags: csv

I have a csv file with traceroutes,
the last entry in every row is the target IP,
but as there are variable no of records in every row ...so I am having difficulty 
I want to collect the last entry from every row into a column

how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a nice function [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Example:

```
if (($handle = fopen("x.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)//your file
{
    echo "<table><tr><th>Row</th><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
    $num_rows = 7440; //number of rows in your CSV file.
    for($w=0; $w<$num_rows; $w++)
    {
        $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
        echo "<tr>
        <td>{$w}</td>
        <td>{$data[0]}</td>
        <td>{$data[1]}</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    fclose($handle);
}
else
{
    die('fopen failed');
}
```

---

To collect the value from the last cell in each row, do the following inside the `for` loop:

```
echo $data[(count($data)-1)];
```

Although, this only needs to be done if the number of cells in each row varies or if you actually don't know.
Otherwise do what's in the example above and just specify it; e.g. if the last cell in each row is always in column C then you collect the value from `$data[2]` (in the `for` loop)